# How to use List<string> inside owned entity

Tags: c#, ef-core-7.0

The simplified version of my model is:

```
public class Product
{
    public Guid guid { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    public required string Name { get; set; }
    public List<string>? Tags { get; set; } = new();
    public List<ProductProperties>? Properties { get; set; }
}

[Owned]
public class ProductProperties
{
    public string? Size { get; set; }
    public string? Color { get; set; }
    //public List<string>? Photos { get; set; } // I'll get error if I uncomment this line
}
```

in model configuration I have added below lines

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>()
    .Property(p => p.Tags).HasConversion<StringListConverter>();

modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().OwnsMany(
    produt => produt.Properties, prodProp =>
    {
        prodProp.ToJson();
    });
```

Note that I'm directly using List in my class and also I'm storing Produt.Properties as JSON column.

Everything works fine until I uncomment the line below in `ProductProperties` class

```
//public List<string>? Photos { get; set; }
```

which gives me below error when adding migration

> The entity type 'List' requires a primary key to be defined.
> If you intended to use a keyless entity type, call 'HasNoKey' in
> 'OnModelCreating'. For more information on keyless entity types, see
> https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2141943

I beleive if I use HasConversion for `Photos` property, I can get rid of the error, but I don't know how to use Fluent API to achieve that. Note that I don't want to have `ProductProperties` as a separate Entity in my database.

`StringListConverter` is a simple class to convert List to comma separated string and vice versa.

Comment: Could it be that it is not supported yet? I do see this [issue](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/issues/29427) on github, but I’m not sure whether it applies to the new Json columns as well

Comment: It seems to be related to what I'm trying to do. Thanks for info.

Comment: Wasn't this supposed to be fixed in .Net 8? I'm doing something familiar, and it looks like it's not working yet.

Comment: @Adnan, in .NET 8, you can use List<string> as json-column in your main entity without any need for conversion. still using List in owned entities not supported

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to make it work like this:

```
[Owned]
public class ProductProperties
{
    public string? Size { get; set; }
    public string? Color { get; set; }

    [NotMapped]
    public List<string>? Photos { get; set; }

    private string PhotosValue
    {
        get { return JsonSerializer.Serialize(Photos); }
        set { Photos = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<string>>(value); }
    }
}
```

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().OwnsMany(
    product => product.Properties, prodProp =>
    {
        prodProp.ToJson();
        prodProp.Property("PhotosValue");
    });
```

Comment: This does what I', looking for. I hope they make it more straight forward in next versions of EF.  I see there are still limitation on filtering on json column. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I finally implemented in another way which seems more satisfying for me.

Because of the limitation(??) on Json column, I need to wrap `List` classes inside another class.

Here is the model and configuration which might be helpful for others:

**Model:**

```
public class Product
{
    public Guid guid { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid();
    public required string Name { get; set; }
    public required ProductProperties Specifications { get; set; }
    public List<StringValue> Tags { get; set; } = new();
}

public class ProductProperty
{
    public string? Size { get; set; }
    public string? Color { get; set; }
    public List<StringValue> Photos { get; set; } = new();
}
```

**Wrapper Classes:**

```
public class StringValue
{
    public required string Value { get; set; }
    public static implicit operator string(StringValue val) => val.Value;
    public static implicit operator StringValue(string val) => new() { Value = val };
}

public class ProductProperties
{
    public List<ProductProperty> Properties { get; set; } = new();
}
```

**Configuration:**

```
modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().OwnsOne(
            produt => produt.Specifications, specsBuilder =>
            {
                specsBuilder.ToJson();
                specsBuilder.OwnsMany(_ => _.Properties, propBuilder =>
                {
                    propBuilder.OwnsMany(prop => prop.Photos);
                });
            });

modelBuilder.Entity<Product>().OwnsMany(
            produt => produt.Tags, tagsBuilder =>
            {
                tagsBuilder.ToJson();
            });
```

Still, filtering on Json column properties not working and I hope it will improve in future updates.